# Re-usable ModalPopupExtender

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, webforms

I am trying to create a ModalPopupExtender that can be stored in a master page, or user control and allow me to pass a panel and an event to it, and use this panel as the panel to be "popped" and the event as the event called when the ok button is pressed.

I've been trying for some time now, with with a number of different methods, but none have worked correctly and the all seem like they're not quite the right way to do it. These include:

- Adding the panel as a child control of another panel that is the Popuptarget of the extender. This does pop the right panel, but because the controls in the panel have been moved out of the childpage, they cannot be accessed in the event.
- Changing the Popuptarget of the extender to be the panel I want to pop, then added a dynamicaly created button with the correct event as the ok button. This again pops the right panel, and calls the right event, but the event is unable to access the controls on the panel again.

So, if anyone can suggest the best way to do this, or any articles where it has been done before, that would be appreciated. The reason I am doing this is that some of the pages we have have upward of 20 different items that may need showing to the user with a modalpopupextender, adding an extender for each of these would be very tiresome.

Comment: Why aren't you using a proper js-library for this? Like jquery. Using jquery creating a modal popup is really easy to create.

Comment: Because I have to use the libraries that are available for use in this project, and that leaves me with the .net Ajax library.

Comment: But jquery is free and also available, and using the features of jayesh is definitely less error prone than writing your own.

Comment: @Tomas - Assuming that Sam is stuck using at least some ASP.Net AJAX then he's probably got an update panel or 20.  I've been to hell and back trying to get jQuery dialogs to work properly in an ASP.Net Update Panel.  It can be done, I've done it, but it's not much fun as you have to re-run the js to create the dialog for any dialogs inside your update panel on each async post back, but don't run it again for those outside the update panel...

Comment: It sounds like you can do what you want, except you can't access the control collection you desire.  Could be namingcontainer issue.  Can you post some code showing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something I had to do couple of years ago, I used the method on ASP.Net forum:

http://forums.asp.net/p/1301694/2541024.aspx

I put a JavaScript function on the masterpage that took in the Panel ID that I wanted to popup, but everything was handled by the panels themselves, no needing to pass events or anything around.

The most I had was two different popup's, no where near your 20.

> Changing the Popuptarget of the extender to be the panel I want to pop, then added a dynamicaly created button with the correct event as the ok button. This again pops the right panel, and calls the right event, but the event is unable to access the controls on the panel again.

Could you explain this a bit more please? Why not have 1 button per panel you are poping up? You have 20 different panels and only 1 of those is active depending on the users request? Or do you need to cycle through different panels?

Could you put some sample code up to show what you're trying to achieve.